# Sendkeys can't input into correct application

Tags: vba, sendkeys

I have the below Excel macro that works fine when I run it directly from Excel. But there is an error when I run it via Python.

The "Send Keys" statement is input into my Python text editor and not the "Dialog" window. So how can I ensure the sendkeys is input into the correct application? Thank you

```
    ChDir "C:\Progra~1\XXX"
    Dialog = Shell("C:\Progra~1\XXX\XXX.exe", 1)
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00.00:5")
    AppActivate Dialog
    SendKeys "input +""C:\programs\yyyy.txt""+{ENTER}", True
```

Comment: _So how can I ensure the sendkeys is input into the correct application?_ You can't. Sendkeys is not safe to use and that is one of the reasons.

Comment: Hi, Sendkeys works perfectly fine when I run the macro directly from Excel.

Comment: Yes, no doubt, but you will not be able to make sure it will hit the application you want  it to hit. https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2013/01/29/problems-with-sendkeys-in-excel/